# Get Class by part of name in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Okay, so I am trying to do my network packet handling in Java using classes. For reading data from my stream I use a DataInputStream. My reading thread for my server looks like this:

```
public void run()
    {
        while(client.isActive())
        {
            try{
                handle(is.readShort());
            }catch (IOException e){
                client.stop(e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I've got a method handle:

```
public void handle(short id) throws IOException
{
    InPacket packet = null;

    try {
        packet = ClassUtils.newInstance(InPacket.class, "server.client.InPacket"+id);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (packet!=null){
        packet.handle(this);
    }
    else{
        throw new IOException("Invalid packet");
    }
}
```

I try to instantiate a new class using the

```
packet = ClassUtils.newInstance(InPacket.class, "server.client.InPacket"+id);
```

line.

In ClassUtils this is that function:

```
public static <T> T newInstance(Class<? extends T> type, String className) throws
ClassNotFoundException,
InstantiationException,
IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Class<? extends T> targetClass = clazz.asSubclass(type);
    T result = targetClass.newInstance();
    return result;
}
```

**My problem is**: when I try to get that class with only part of the name (I try to get it by "InPacket1", while the class is called "InPacket1Connect"), it can't find it. Is it possible to do this in Java, and if so how? If not, what method do you recommend for handling my network packets?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use `newInstance()` for this?

Comment: I need to create an instance of a Packet class, and then handle that instance, because I want to handle my networking in separate classes per packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to use a map (or enum) which maps the id to the full class name.

Pulling in the stuff from the comments, ensure that this mapping class is available as a jar (or may be in the same jar which contains the implementations of the packet handlers) as your "messaging layer" jar.

Comment: Because I am gonna need quite a few packets, and it's inefficient to have to map every packet to a classname both in the Client and Server project.

Comment: @Gmfreaky, how is it inefficient? One class which does the mapping (heck you could use an enum), and more importantly you'll have explicit control (and guaranteed behaviour). IMO I don't think it's very clear what you expect to achieve, I've personally never encountered this design in nearly 5 years of working with distributed systems....

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear, but I mean it's efficient to implement extra packets. For every packet I add I must edit two extra classes (one for the server and for the client). I think I will go with that solution though for stability. Thanks for answering :-)

Comment: @Gmfreaky, you don't need to edit two classes - have a single enum which does the mapping and the instantiation based on the value of that enum, and share this jar across the server and client. When you have a new message - publish a new version of this jar. For future proofing, ensure that you have a mechanism to skip a message of a client/server version doesn't understand the message (say include a size, so it can skip that many bytes etc.)

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Like this, maybe?

```
packet = ClassUtils.newInstance(InPacket.class, "server.client.InPacket"+id+"Connect");
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

(but I may have misunderstood your question)

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know the full name of the class, I just name my classes like InPacket0Function or InPacket1Test. The number indicates the id of the packet in the code. So for instance I want to select the class that's called InPacket4Foo. I know the id is 4, but I don't know that it's called Foo after that.

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not create the full class name?

```
packet = ClassUtils.newInstance(InPacket.class, "server.client.InPacket"+id + "Connect"
```

You could implement the functionality you seem to be asking for - a kind of "fuzzy" classname matching - by writing your own classloader. The classloader could search some directories for class files partially matching the type.

My feeling is that this is potentially a brittle solution, there's a danger of loading unexpected classes. I prefer Nim's suggestion of explicitly having a mapping table if you can't use an algorthimic classname generator.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer! I name the packets after what they do. For instance, InPacket1Connect is a packet from the client with the client's name that indicates that he connected. Explicitly making a map for all the packets will make it harder to add packets to the software, since I have to also add it in a map, both in my Server and Client project.

Comment: it's a trade off. More control at the expense of more work, flexibility against brittleness. As systems grow I tend to favour operational stability and clarity. If you get the mapping from a file, it's a quick edit to update the file - overhead will not be very great.